# Not able to set value of hidden field using viewbag when value is type of bool.

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc

Controller side i have

`ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Cookies["SignInOption"]["Can Add New Student"].Split(',')[0]);`

And at the view side i take Hidden field as

```
 <input type="hidden" id="HiddenCanAddNewStudent" value="@ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent">
      <label>@ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent</label>
```

Here in Hidden field i get Value="value" instead of Boolean value.[image]

Comment: It is possible when i pass value as string
ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent = Request.Cookies["SignInOption"]["Can Add New Student"].Split(',')[0];
I can't understand what is problem with Boolean value.

    @Html.Hidden("HiddenCanAddNewStudent", (bool)ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent) Is also working the only problem is <input type="hidden">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an unfortunate side effect of a feature introduced in Razor V2 called conditional attributes. If the value of the property is a `bool` it will repeat the attribute and is designed for use in attributes such as `checked` or `disabled` where you can use a `bool` value and if the value is `true` it will generate `checked="checked"` or `disabled="disabled"`, but if the value is `false` then the attribute will be omitted.

You can read more about this feature in [Cleaner Conditional HTML Attributes In Razor Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/201/cleaner-conditional-html-attributes-in-razor-web-pages) and [Applying Conditional Attributes in ASP.NET MVC Views](http://rion.io/2013/11/23/applying-conditional-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-views/)

To generate the hidden input, you can use

```
@Html.Hidden("HiddenCanAddNewStudent", ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent)
```

which will also include a `name="HiddenCanAddNewStudent"` attribute in addition to the `id="HiddenCanAddNewStudent"` attribute. However, the MVC way to handle this is to use a view model that includes a property for your bool

```
public bool CanAddNewStudent { get; set; }
```

and set the value of that property before you pass the model to the view, then in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CanAddNewStudent)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is how boolean values usually work in HTML (for example, in checkboxes) -- the logical value is represented not by the value of attribute value, but by its presence (if the tag has this attribute, the value is true, otherwise false). It is really strange that this logic is applied to hidden fields, but probably the framework works this way.

Anyway, I would recommend to convert the boolean value into a string and assign this string to the field. By their nature, values of hidden fields are strings, not booleans.

Comment: As i mentioned in comment when i pass string value it is working, but i can't understand strange behavior of "Hidden Fields".

Answer (score 0):

At top of View take **boolean variable** and save viewbag value in it and then pass that variable to your hiddenfield.

```
@{
    bool _canAddNewStudent=Convert.ToBoolean(Viewbag.CanAddNewStudent);
}

<input type="hidden" id="HiddenCanAddNewStudent" value="@_canAddNewStudent">
```

Answer (score 0):

View(html)

```
<label id="HiddenCanAddNewStudent" style="display:none;">@ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent</label>
```

jQuery
`$('#HiddenCanAddNewStudent').text();` //value of ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to use input tag

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenCanAddNewStudent" value=@Convert.ToString(ViewBag.CanAddNewStudent)>
```

this will return true in jQuery and also show in HTML value ="True"